# Как лучше реализовать сохранение в базу данных цифр взятых с html страницы?

Tags: python, парсер, cron

В локальной сети есть html страница на которой каждые 0,2сек показывается уровень воды. Нужно сделать график этих показателей с шагом 1 сек, и чтобы можно было смотреть историю. (с самой html страницой ничего сделать нельзя, только смотреть данные в реальном времени, они обновляются через ajax)
Как это лучше реализовать?

Я думаю, что можно попробовать написать парсер на python и сохранять в базу MySQL, а потом уже из MySQL доставить эти данные как угодно. Тогда вопрос в том, как сделать, чтобы парсер постоянно работал на сервере? Крон?

Comment: а просто цикл не подходит с задеожкой на 1 сек?

Answer (score 0):

1 вариант. зациклить скрипт через "while true" с задержкой в одну секунду.

```
import time

while True:
    # do someting
    time.sleep(1)
```

2 вариант. Через планировщик задач в определенное время запускать ваш скрипт.

Да, и проще использовать SQLlite3, так как она "встроена" в python